# woocommerce UPS rates to have USD converted rates from INR on plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I am using woocommerce to build a ecommerce site and I use UPS shipping to do shipping, the ups I have signed is from India so the returned rates are in Indian Currency. Is there a way to convert the currency from INR to convert to USD and display the price to the customers of my site. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge if your woocommerce by default currency is dollar then currency always comes in same the currency.Can you please share your site Url then I can check what is the problem?